# Events in SharePoint 2010: how do I tackle this?

Tags: 2010

I have a request for a creating an event management subsite. You should be able to create, edit and delete events, invite people for events, RSVP for events, add comments to an event, add pictures to an event,etc.

This could be done by giving each event its own subsite, without any issue. However, can this be done using a list with list-items (each record is an event on its own) without extensive coding and modding?

I'm looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to tie this together with Outlook/Exchange and then create the event in Outlook, invite people and then [create a Meeting Workspace](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2009/sharepoint-meeting-workspace-sites-how-and-why/) for the event.  This effectively creates a new subsite for each Event/Meeting but keeps it tied together and allows people to be invited (and RSVP by accepting the invite) using a tool they are already familiar with - Outlook.

However, the above solution only works with events that are centered around people who work for the company and their immediate contacts.  It would not work if you are setting up generic events for public users.  That would require a different approach.